# Auto populating attribute table with lat and lon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, latitude-longitude

is there a simple way (without writing script or Python skills) to auto calculate and auto populate `lat` and `lon` attributes in QGIS?

When I manually add new points or move existing points in my layer, I'd like the `lat` and `lon` attributes to be captured and the attribute table populated/updated as I complete the task. Right now, I create or modify the points and then update the attribute table with `$y` and `$x` in the Field Calculator.

Comment: use a virtual field or an auto-updating default field value